# Windows 10 IoT Core terminates connection to XBox 360 wireless game controller after app start

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core, xbox360, appxmanifest

I have a XBox 360 Controller attached, using the `XBox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows` USB dongle, to my `Windows 10 IoT Core (Build: 17763)` machine.

The receiver shows up in the dashboard and I can navigate in the left-sided burger menu.

If I start and deploy via Visual Studio 2019 my app to the Pi, the yellow light on the Receiver goes off and the controller has no longer a connection to the Pi.

I looked for suitable capabilities in the `Package.appxmanifest` file but there was no good sounding one. I searched for HID, HUD, USB, Gamepad, etc.

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="usage:0001 0004"/>
        <Function Type="usage:0001 0005"/>
      </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

But this did not solve my problem.

**Update**
I tested it with a wired XBox 360 controller, there is no such problem.

Comment: Which target version did you select for the project? The capability configuration is ok in Package.appxmanifest.

Comment: I use as minimum and as target version 1809 build 17736

Comment: Please use Feedback Hub app to report this issue. The Feedback Hub app lets you tell Microsoft about any problems you run in to while using Windows 10 and send suggestions to help us improve your Windows experience.